# get MPEG-TS stream media info

Tags: java, video

I'm making a player that can play an MPEG-TS stream and display all its videos at once (for monitoring purposes) in one frame using Xuggler for JAVA.

My problem is getting to determine what programs this stream holds (tv programs) and what are its streams...

for example : audio stream 1 and video stream 3 belong to program "BBC".

Now I already got it working for a .ts file by using MediaInfo http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/  like so :

MediaInfo.exe -LogFile="log.txt" "some .ts file" .... which logs a file like this :

```
Menu #2
ID                                       : 1001 (0x3E9)
Menu ID                                  : 1202 (0x4B2)
Duration                                 : 13mn 33s
List                                     : 2001 (0x7D1) (MPEG Video) / 3002 (0xBBA) (MPEG Audio, English)
Language                                 :  / English
Service name                             : NBN
Service provider                         : NILESAT
Service type                             : digital television
UTC 2006-03-28 00:00:00                  : en:NBN / en:Nilesat /  /  / 99:00:00 / Running
```

and then I parsed the file in java

but I need to make this work for a live stream and when I give MediaInfo a URL instead of a file it gives this error :

> Libcurl library not found

I also tried vlc commands but turns out it doesn't have this option and only available in gui (show codec information)...

the player is already working and I got an extractor too... just need this media info to work... any ideas?

EDIT : I found out FFprobe which is bundled with FFmpeg http://www.ffmpeg.org/ can do the task
but for some reason I can't read anything from the input stream.
Here's what the output looks like:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'D:\record ts\PBR_REC_20140426094852_484.ts':
Duration: N/A, start: 6164.538011, bitrate: N/A
Program 1201
Metadata:
  service_name    : Arabica TV
  service_provider: Nilesat
Stream #0:10[0x7db]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv42
0p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2348 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50
tbc
Stream #0:4[0xbcf]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s
Program 1202
```

I tried this in JAVA:

```
 try {
        Process process ;
        
        Scanner sc;
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\vlatkozelka\\Desktop\\ffmpeg-20140623-git-ca35037-win64-static\\bin\\ffprobe.exe","-i",filename);
        
        process=processBuilder.start();
        sc=new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
        process=processBuilder.start();
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
        
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChannelDivider.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

but the `sc.hasNext()` just hangs like there is no input
then I tried writing to a file with cmd by using  > but it gave me a blank file

however trying both methods with FFprobe -h (help command) does give output which is very much confusing me, I see output in cmd but cant read it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this, and hope someone might make use of it:
it turns out that FFprobe was writing to stderr, not stdout,
so instead of:

```
getInputStream()
```

I used:

```
getErrorStream()
```

Now all I have to do is parse that :)